# Why does blocked IO in another thread prevent CreateWindowEx() from returning

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, io, nonblocking

I have a very simple Windows console application that first creates a thread to process input on stdin. It uses `CreateThread()` in `main()` to create the thread, and the first thing the thread does is call `getchar()` and block, waiting.

Then `main()` registers a window class using `RegisterClass()` and calls `CreateWindowEx()` to create an invisible message window.

BUT `CreateWindowEx()` never returns.

If I remove the `getchar()` in the thread and replace it with `while (1) Sleep(1000);`, everything works.

If I add `Sleep(1000);` to the start of the thread function, the `CreateWindowEx()` call succeeds but then the I/O in the thread stops working (`getchar()` doesn't return).

Why is the blocked 2nd thread interfering with the first?

Comment: What's going on in your window procedure?  Do you receive `WM_NC_CREATE`?

Comment: The window procedure just calls DefWindowProc() unless it's a WM_USER message, in which case it logs that to a file. This works if I don't call getchar() in the thread. I don't know if WM_NC_CREATE is being sent to it.

Comment: Can you provide [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C runtime library doesn't officially support being called from a thread spawned with `CreateThread`.  You're supposed to use the CRT wrapper functions such as `_beginthreadex`, which properly configure CRT thread-local state on the new thread.

In practice, the CRT goes to great lengths to make things work even if you break that rule, but the details depend on whether you're statically or dynamically linking with the CRT (since that affects whether there's a `THREAD_ATTACH` callback).

Try doing it "right" by only making CRT calls on threads started with `_beginthreadex`.  (One way is to keep using `CreateThread` and then use `ReadConsole` in the worker thread instead of `getchar`, the other is to use `_beginthreadex` instead of `CreateThread`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Ben. I tried quickly changing the thread code to use _beginthread() and it did not make a difference. It still hangs inside CreateWindowEx(). I also tinkered with getting ReadConsole() to work instead but this proved challenging. I'm not sure why it's not working just yet.

Comment: I could not get this to work using _beginthreadex() but was finally able to get it to work by using ReadFile() and WriteFile() to replace all stdio functions. Thanks Ben!

Comment: @Nicholas: You're welcome.  And yes, `ReadFile` is a good choice for I/O, including console I/O, if you're only interested in the character data.  `ReadConsole` provides character data (keyboard and clipboard) plus mouse as well.